# CSS Table Sorting treats numbers like strings in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I have my order and reverse function correctly in angular but when I click 
    to sort, it sorts numbers like strings `(i.e. 333, 32, 331).`  I think I have 
    to cast the values as numbers, but I'm not really sure how to do that with 
    an array.

```
key = 'name'; 
reverse = false;
SortList(key) {
   this.key = key;
   this.reverse = !this.reverse;
}
======HTML======
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Add</th>
      <th (click)="SortList('name')">Name
      <span *ngIf="key == 'name'">
          <span *ngIf="reverse">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="!reverse">
              <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
          </span>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let t of lastSeasonQB | orderBy: key : reverse>
      <td class="name-left-padding">{{t.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>`
    `</table>`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only array something like this ["333", "32", "331"]. You can use **Map** function of array to convert each value in number format.

```
var a = ["333", "32", "331"];
// console.log(a[0]+a[1]); //print 12
var b = a.map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});
// console.log(b[0]+b[1]); //print 3
```

If it is array of Object then you have find each Object and find the value to convert it into number.